# 7X7(Borrowed words Puzzle)

Tags: word, word-square, crossword-clues

7X7(Borrowed words Puzzle)

Note : The main purpose of this puzzle is not just for someone to answer it, but I hope someone can also Tell what types of this puzzle is exactly,as you can see i just wrote the title with (Borrowed words Puzzle).And i think this puzzle not really  hard  to solving.

```
                      .
                         1 2 3 4 5 6 7
                       8 X X X X X X X
                       9 X X X X X X X
                      10 X X X X X X X
                      11 X X X X X X X
                      12 X X X X X X X
                      13 X X X X X X X
                      14 X X X X X X X
                      .
```

### VERTICAL

> - (1) _ _ _ _ _ _ _. To turn into prose
> - (2) _ _ _ _ _ _ _. Daughter of Latinus and Amata
> - (3) _ _ _ _ _ _ _. Hasty glance
> - (4) Let not the _ _ _ _ _ _ _ Oule, nor the Storke be heard.
> - (5.1) _ _ _ _ _ _ _. Scrap, misunderstanding, difference
> - (5.2) _ _ _ _ _ _ _. Built across a stream or river
> - (6.1) _ _. Identity verifiers
> - (6.2) _ _ _. Present indicative plural
> - (6.3) _ _. Second most populous city in the United States
> - (7) _ _ _ _ _ _ _. Wax derived from ozokerite

---

### HORIZONTAL

> - (8) _ _ _ _ _ _ _. Synthetic or semi-synthetic organic compounds
> - (9) _ _ _ _ _ _ _. Needle shaped crystals of calcium oxalate
> - (10) _ _ _ _ _ _ _. Too great a distance
> - (11.1) _ _ _ _. The assistant uses voice queries and a natural-language user interface to answer questions
> - (11.2) _ _ _. European Union Agency for Fundamental Rights
> - (12) _ _ _ _ _ _ _. Second person singular
> - (13.1) _ _ _ _. Only national source for comparable and consistent financial information for Canadian universities
> - (13.2) _ _ _. American professional boxer
> - (14.1) _ _ _ _. Popular Indian actor born on 8 January 1986
> - (14.2) _ _ _ . Adult male

Comment: This is a [word square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Final grid

> ```
>    PLASTIC
>    RAPHIDE
>    OVERFAR
>    SIRIFRA
>    INCEDES
>    FIUCALI
>    YASHMAN
> ```

Explanation of clues

> (1) PROSIFY To turn into prose
>  (2) LAVINIA Daughter of Latinus and Amata
>  (3) APERCUS. Hasty glance
>  (4) Let not the SHRIECH Oule, nor the Storke be heard.
>  (5.1) TIFF. Scrap, misunderstanding, difference
>  (5.2) DAM. Built across a stream or river
>  (6.1) ID. Identity verifiers
>  (6.2) ARE. Present indicative plural
>  (6.3) LA. Second most populous city in the United States
>  (7) CERASIN. Wax derived from ozokerite
>  (8) PLASTIC. Synthetic or semi-synthetic organic compounds
>  (9) RAPHIDE. Needle shaped crystals of calcium oxalate
>  (10) OVERFAR. Too great a distance
>  (11.1) SIRI. The assistant uses voice queries and a natural-language user interface to answer questions
>  (11.2) FRA. European Union Agency for Fundamental Rights
>  (12) INCEDES? Second person singular
>  (13.1) FIUC. Only national source for comparable and consistent financial information for Canadian universities
>  (13.2) ALI. American professional boxer
>  (14.1) YASH. [Popular Indian actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yash_(actor)) born on 8 January 1986
>  (14.2) MAN. Adult male

Some errors, some suggestions:

> (1), (6.1) - It is highly frowned upon to repeat words in your clue (even with slightly edited forms. PROSIFY and PROSE, for instance.
>  (3) - Tense error, APERCUS is plural.
>  (5.1), (5.2) - wrong enumeration
>  I don't get the clue for (12).

Comment: nice! All correct ,,and thanks about suggestion ,sorry about number 3 ,i don't know how to escape from  using Apercus ,and number 12  INCEDES ,is latin word.

Comment: Right, APERCUS is a fun word, it just had to be indicated as a plural (e.g. "Hasty glances"). Similarly non-English really should be indicated. Also, the tense really isn't sufficient for INCEDES - from Wiktionary, INCEDES is the second person singular of INCEDO, which means to march. So I guess a clue for INCEDES could be "In Latin, the word 'march' in 'You march'". But it's probably best to stay away from such words in the first place.

Comment: Edit to add - since you're willing to take multiple words, it may be better to clue INCEDES as two words: IN and CEDES.

Answer (score 5):

### Answer

```
                     1 2 3 4 5 6 7  
                   8 P L A S T I C  
                   9 R A P H I D E  
                  10 O V E R F A R  
                  11 S I R I F R A  
                  12 I N C E D E S  
                  13 F I U C A L I  
                  14 Y A S H M A N
```

### Clue-by-clue explanation

1. To turn into prose (7)

   > [PROSIFY](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prosify).
2. Daughter of Latinus and Amata (7)

   > [LAVINIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavinia).
3. Hasty glance (7)

   > APERCUS.
4. Let not the _ _ _ _ _ _ _ Oule, nor the Storke be heard (7)

   > [SHRIECH](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/epithalamion).

5.1. Scrap, misunderstanding, difference (7, should be 4)

> TIFF.

5.2. Built across a stream or river (7, should be 3)

> DAM.

6.1. Identity verifiers (2)

> ID.

6.2. Present indicative plural (3)

> ARE.

6.3. Second most populous city in the United States (2)

> [LA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_population).

7. Wax derived from ozokerite (7)

   > [CERASIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceresin).
8. Synthetic or semi-synthetic organic compounds (7)

   > PLASTIC.
9. Needle shaped crystals of calcium oxalate (7)

   > [RAPHIDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphide).
10. Too great a distance (7)

    > OVERFAR.

11.1. The assistant uses voice queries and a natural-language user interface to answer questions (4)

> [SIRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siri).

11.2. European Union Agency for Fundamental Rights

> [FRA](European Union Agency for Fundamental Rights).

12. Second person singular (7)

    > [INCEDES](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incedes)?

13.1. Only national source for comparable and consistent financial information for Canadian universities (4)

> [FIUC](https://www.caubo.ca/knowledge-centre/surveysreports/fiuc-reports/).

13.2. American professional boxer (3)

> [ALI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Al).

14.1. Popular Indian actor born on 8 January 1986

> [YASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yash_(actor)).

14.2. Adult male

> MAN.

### Feedback section

Some of the clues were *way* easier than others.

- The first ones I solved were 2 (easily Googlable) and 14.2 (obvious).
- 4, 11.2, 13.1 were also easily Googlable. 14.1 surprisingly *wasn't*.
- 3 and 12 were basically impossible without a lot of letters already filled in.
- 7 and 9 were also very hard, and not as Googlable as they looked. (I kept thinking 7 would be "paraffin", and wondering if "parafin" is a valid alternative spelling.)

It also feels as though a lot of the words were shoehorned in to fit into the word square you already had. It's possible to make word squares which feel much more natural, although of course a $7\times7$ one will always be challenging. *CUBE UGLY BLUE EYES* is a famous example, and I've easily created more in $4\times4$ and $5\times5$ size.

Comment: nice! All correct ,,and thanks about suggestion ,sorry about that,this is my first time creating the  puzzle .like that..

Comment: No worries! It was fun to solve :-)